# how to writes test case in rails for html content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Any one help me?

This is my rspec_controller.rb

```
it "#save_request" do
    expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    expect(response).not_to have_http_status(302)
    should have_content("Success")
end
```

This is my console error:

```
1) TimeslotsController#request_timeslot_create #save_request
     Failure/Error: should have_content("Success")
       expected #<TimeslotsController:0xcc2746c> to respond to `has_content?`
     # ./spec/controllers/timeslots_controller_spec.rb:46:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For html_content better use rspec + capybara, and write feature test.
[capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara)
then you can write `expect(page).to have_content("Success")`
If you really want to use just rspec controller here is guide
[Rspec render views](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/render-views)

And last thing name of controller spec should be like: `timeslots_controller_spec.rb`

Comment: i got this error :(
NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `page' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::TimeslotsController::RequestTimeslotCreate:0xc919978>

Comment: you can use `page` only in capybara feature tests. The error has TimeslotsController::RequestTimeslotCreate so, you are doing controller type test with action create. There you have to use response.body as in guide.